# What's the difference between [NSNull null] and nil?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, null, nsnull

Here's a context where I have seen that:

```
NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < kNumberOfPages; i++) {
    [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
```

why not nil in that place?

Comment: Doesn't get any better than this ---> http://nshipster.com/nil/

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Directly from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html):

> The NSNull class defines a singleton object you use to represent null values in situations where nil is prohibited as a value (typically in a collection object such as an array or a dictionary).

So in your example, that's exactly what's happening, the programmer is choosing to put a null object into the controllers array, where nil is not allowed as a value.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot add a `nil` value to an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`. If you need to store a `nil` value, you need to use the `NSNull` wrapper class, as shown in that snippet you have. This is specified in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObject:).

Answer (score 11):

We all agree that [NSNull null] is useful as a placeholder where an object is required, as elaborated above. But unless it's explicitly used in assignment for your object, it should not be used in comparison, a mistake I have made in the past.

```
id a;
NSLog(@"Case 1");
if (a == nil) NSLog(@"a == nil");
if (a == Nil) NSLog(@"a == Nil");
if ([a isEqual:[NSNull null]]) NSLog(@"a isEqual:[NSNull null]");

NSLog(@"Case 2");
a = [NSNull null];
if (a == nil) NSLog(@"a == nil");
if (a == Nil) NSLog(@"a == Nil");
if ([a isEqual:[NSNull null]]) NSLog(@"a isEqual:[NSNull null]");
```

Output:

2014-01-31 10:57:11.179 MCDocsApp[13266:a0b] Case 1

2014-01-31 10:57:11.179 MCDocsApp[13266:a0b] a == nil

2014-01-31 10:57:11.179 MCDocsApp[13266:a0b] a == Nil

2014-01-31 10:57:11.180 MCDocsApp[13266:a0b] Case 2

2014-01-31 10:57:11.180 MCDocsApp[13266:a0b] a isEqual:[NSNull null]

Comment: `-[NSObject isEqual:]` is the correct and recommended method to compare an objc object with NSNull.

Comment: Newly-alloc’d NSObjects start life with their contents set to 0. This means that all pointers that object has to other objects begin as nil, so it’s unnecessary to, for instance, set self.(association) = nil in init methods. In case 1, "a" has default value 0 which indicates nil/Nil and for second case you assigns singleton object used to represent null, that is why it outputs null not nil.

Answer (score 9):

Collection classes like `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` cannot contain `nil` values. **`NSNULL` was created specifically as a placeholder for `nil`. It can be put into collection classes**, and only takes up space.

`NSNull` defines a singleton object, which means that there's only ever a single instance of NSNull (which you create using `[NSNull null]`), but it can be used in as many places as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

***The NSNull class defines a singleton object you use to represent null values in situations where nil is prohibited as a value (typically in a collection object such as an array or a dictionary).***

You cannot add a nil value to an NSArray or NSMutableArray. If you need to store a nil value, you need to use the NSNull wrapper class.

Collection classes like NSArray and NSDictionary cannot contain nil values. NSNULL was created specifically as a placeholder for nil. It can be put into collection classes, and only takes up space.

See the link for reference

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html

Answer (score -15):

nil marks the end of an array after an array of objects...