# What does 'Nil' represent in Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c

So there 's `NULL`, which is used for pointers in general, and `nil`, which is used for object pointers.

Now I see there's also `Nil`, which is used by lower-level Obj-C runtime functions like `class_getProperty`.

Is this somehow different from `nil` philosophically? (yes, I know they're all actually 0)

Why was it even introduced? Or, if `Nil` was first (which is likely), why was `nil` introduced?

Comment: Exact duplicate, though in different words from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836601

Comment: That is actually quite different.

Comment: I agree, it's not a duplicate of that question. [NSNull null] returns an object, where as nil/Nil/NULL are all various forms of 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Googling "Nil vs nil" found this post http://numbergrinder.com/node/49, which states:

> All three of these values represent
>   null, or zero pointer, values. The
>   difference is that while NULL
>   represents zero for any pointer, nil
>   is specific to objects (e.g., id) and
>   Nil is specific to class pointers. It
>   should be considered a best practice
>   of sorts to use the right null object
>   in the right circumstance for
>   documentation purposes, even though
>   there is nothing stopping someone from
>   mixing and matching as they go along.

Comment: Yup, I've seen that page, but I didn't believe it was just for Class pointers. Now, after reading <objc/objc.h>, it seems this really is the case :)

Comment: What is the class objects and obj c objects where I can use nil,Nil