# iPhone : Difference between nil vs Nil and true vs TRUE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What is difference between `nil` and `Nil` in iOS development?

And similarly what is difference between `true` and `TRUE` in iOS development?

Comment: The below answer may help you in some way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908936/iphonedifference-between-nil-nil-and-null

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this will help you understand the difference between `nil` and `Nil`.

**Please find the below link:**

Refer the answer of Damien_The_Unbeliever which states:

Googling "Nil vs nil" found this post http://numbergrinder.com/node/49, which states:

> All three of these values represent null, or zero pointer, values. The
>   difference is  that while NULL represents zero for any pointer, nil is
>   specific to objects (e.g., id)  and Nil is specific to class pointers.
>   It should be considered a best practice of sorts to use the right null
>   object in the right circumstance for documentation purposes, even
>   though there is nothing stopping someone from mixing and matching as
>   they go along.

**Link for that answer can be seen here:**

[What does 'Nil' represent in Obj-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299689/what-does-nil-represent-in-obj-c)

**EDIT-2:**

[Is there a difference between YES/NO,TRUE/FALSE and true/false in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615702/is-there-a-difference-between-yes-no-true-false-and-true-false-in-objective-c)

Comment: Please check the EDIT-2 Section of the answer. It explained TRUE vs true vs YES.

Comment: Parth Bhatt - What is the difference between id and a class pointer? It is said that nil is specific to object and Nil represents a class poiter. Please elaborate

Comment: what a horrible language design

Answer (score 7):

nil is the literal null value for Objective-C objects, corresponding to the abstract type id or any Objective-C type declared via @interface. For instance:

```
NSString *someString = nil;
NSURL *someURL = nil;
id someObject = nil;

if (anotherObject == nil) // do something
```

Nil is the literal null value for Objective-C classes, corresponding to the type Class. Since most code doesn’t need variables to reference classes, its use is not common. One example is:

```
 Class someClass = Nil;
 Class anotherClass = [NSString class];
```