# Nil and nil - difference

Tags: objective-c, null

What is difference between `nil` and `Nil`?  `nil` is an uninitialised object, what is about `Nil`? Thanks!

Comment: it should help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578748/iphone-difference-between-nil-vs-nil-and-true-vs-true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the zero value for the `Class` type.

All of `NULL`, `nil`, `Nil`, `NUL`, `'\0'`, `0`, `0L`, `0U`, `0.0`, `0.0f`, ... have the same value (at least on sane systems). They just correspond to different types.

And to make this clear: `nil` is not an "uninitialized object" but the value of an (initialized) variable of object pointer type.

Comment: Thanks! "You can accept an answer in 9 minutes". I will accept your answer soon!

Comment: `Nil` is from `NeXTSTEP`, not from Russia. Both have seen better times.

Comment: @nicael Would that imply something about my credibility?

Answer (score 2):

> `nil` is an uninitialised object

No, it isn't. It's a pointer-to-object that points nowhere. Uninitialized objects need **not** be `nil`.

> what is about `Nil`

It's similar, but instead of objects, it is for classes only. (Since classes **are** objects in Objective-C, you could use `nil` for a pointer of type `Class` as well, but that is discouraged for code readability reasons.)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a bit of pedantry....

`nil` is a value that represents a pointer to a valid non-object.  From a C perspective, it is a pointer to nowhere.  However, it has special meanings in the context of Objective-C.  Because Objective-C is a *nil eats messages* language, assigning `nil` to an object pointer will make that object pointer effectively a no-op in all subsequent messaging operations.

`nil`'s value is defined as 0, but -- technically -- it doesn't have to be represented by zero bits (though it actually has to compare as equal to zero).  [Because standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894013/is-null-always-zero-in-c).

In practice, `nil` will be 0 exactly as Nikolai indicates.

`Nil` is the same as `nil`, but for Class object references as H2C03 mentions.