# UITableViewCell not Display Subtitle when i am set the initwithstyle:UItableviewsubtitle

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellidenti = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:cellidenti];

    if(cell == Nil)
    {
        cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellidenti];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = isActive?searchData[indexPath.row]:tableData[indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = isActive?searchNumberData[indexPath.row]:tableNumberData[indexPath.row];   
    return cell;
}
```

i am not getting perfect view and i am not using storyboard.

Comment: use static NSString *cellidenti = @"Cell";

Comment: What are you trying to do with this : `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:cellidenti];
` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things i have observed in code

1) Use `correct way of cell reusability` using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` (as others already suggested). Also have a look at another way of reusability of cell [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:) using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`.

2) Try to use `nil` instead of `Nil`. Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578748/iphone-difference-between-nil-vs-nil-and-true-vs-true).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellidenti = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidenti];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellidenti];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = isActive?searchData[indexPath.row]:tableData[indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = isActive?searchNumberData[indexPath.row]:tableNumberData[indexPath.row];   
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not using correct way of reusable cell's instance and also use static cell identifier. so for more info see below code in edited section....

```
-UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellidenti = @"Cell";// edited here.....
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidenti];// edited here

    if(cell == Nil)
    {
        cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellidenti];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = isActive?searchData[indexPath.row]:tableData[indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = isActive?searchNumberData[indexPath.row]:tableNumberData[indexPath.row];   
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is in this line `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:cellidenti];` This will return `UIView`, not `UITableviewCell`. Instead, you can use below line.

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidenti];
```

Answer (score 0):

USe `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` for creating reuse instance