# Compare to null in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am beginning to find my code littered with:

```
if([p objectForKey@"somekey"] != [NSNull null]) {

}
```

Is there shorter (character-wise) comparison for NULL?

Background: I am using the SBJson library to parse a JSON string and there are often null values (by design) for some of the keys.

Comment: The objectForKey method does not return [NSNull null].  It returns nil.

Comment: This could give you a false positive. If `[p objectForKey:@"someKey"] returns `nil`, your test will pass.

Comment: It returns `[NSNull null]` if that's what's in the dictionary.

Comment: @jarmod Unless the object stored for `@"someKey"` is `NSNull`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836601/whats-the-difference-between-nsnull-null-and-nil for the distinction.

Comment: Yeah, good points about actually storing [NSNull null] in the dictionary.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: There seems to be confusion here about the OP's question. Read the "Background." He's asking what he means to ask.

Comment: I'd like to reopen this question. It is not a duplicate. The question is not how NSNull differs from nil, but programmer-efficient ways to test for NSNull.

Comment: @RobNapier You are indeed correct and your answer is more inline with the actual question. I read the question rather quickly and since he is checking for NSNull *incorrectly* my answer was in respons to that  issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing built-in, but it would be reasonable and simple to create a function `MYIsNull()` that would do the comparison you want. Just think through what you want to return in the case that the key is missing.

You may want to go the other way and transform `-null` into `nil`. For instance, you could add a category on `NSDictionary` like this:

```
- (id)my_nonNullObjectForKey:(NSString *)key {
   id value = [self objectForKey:key];
   if ([value isEqual:[NSNull null]) {
     return nil;
   }
   return value;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. We Objective-C programmers are much more used to dealing with `nil`, and being able to use our usual patterns like `if (!myString) ...` is a big plus.

Comment: Prefix that method, please, if you add it as a category on `NSDictionary`.

Comment: (For those following along at home, read "Avoid Category Method Name Clashes" at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html. It really does matter, and it really has blown up quite badly in my face.)

Answer (score 5):

I would use

```
if([[p objectForKey@"somekey"] isEqual:[NSNull null]] || ![p objectForKey@"somekey"]) {
    // NSNull or nil
} else {
    // Stuff exists...Hurray!
}
```

It seem to work since `[NSNull null]` is in fact an "object". Hope it helps!

Comment: While better coding, it does kind of work in the opposite direction of the OP's goal (in that it's actually longer than what it replaces).

Comment: This is the best solution.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the actual question?

Answer (score 3):

No, you have to test for `NSNull`.  However, if you're finding your code is being littered by it, you might want to create a `#define` for it.

Bear in mind also that if `p` is nil, or if `p` doesn't have a value for `someKey`, then `[p objectForKey@"somekey"] != [NSNull null]` evaluates to `YES`.

So you probably want something like this:

```
#define IsTruthy(X) ( X && (X != [NSNull null]) )
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there shorter (character-wise) comparison for NULL?

`[NSNull null]` is 13 chars. You can say:

```
NSNull.null // << 11
(id)kCFNull // << 11
```

Or make a function:

```
IsNSNull([p objectForKey@"somekey"]) // << 10 in this case and requires no ==, !=
```

Or (cringes) use a category:

```
[p objectForKey@"somekey"].mon_isNSNull // << 13 in this case, but requires no ==, !=
```

Just be careful how you name that category when dealing with `nil` receivers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `SBJSON`, you can easily change its code - you have the source.

I have actually modified `SBJSON` parser to skip `[NSNull null]` values. They are not added to the dictionaries and when I call `objectForKey:`, I never get `[NSNull null]`, I just get `nil`. Then, in most situation I don't even have to check if the value is `nil` since calling a method on `nil` usually gives the result I expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just worried about the amount of time your taking to type, consider macros:

```
#define ISNULL(key) [p objectForKey:key] == [NSNull null]
```

then

```
if (!ISNULL(@"somekey")) ...
```

Answer (score -4):

Pretty sure you can just say

```
if ([p objectForKey:@"somekey"]) {

}
```

I don't use NSNull much so I'm not 100% sure but I think it tests as false and any other object tests as true.

Comment: If the value for 'someKey' is in fact `NSNull`, this test will pass. This if statement is equivelent to `if ([p objectForKey:@"someKey"] == nil )`

Comment: I downvoted because I'm pretty sure this is incorrect. Could you please test it to be sure?