# How to create 2-dimensional array with nil elements

Tags: ios, multidimensional-array, nsmutablearray, nsarray, null

In a chess game I would like to use a 2-dimensional array to track positions of pieces at the chess board.

Initially I thought to create an `NSMuteableArray` and indicate unoccupied squares by `nil`. The occupied slots should hold a pointer to a `Piece` object...

However the following code:

```
NSMutableArray* _board;
...

_board = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *row = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        [row addObject:nil];
    }
    [_board addObject:row];
}
```

fails with the runtime error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

So `nil` can't be passed as argument to `addObject`... what to do here instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
NSMutableArray* _board;
...

_board = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *row = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        [row addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
    [_board addObject:row];
}
```

Reason for using `[NSNull null]` instead of `nil` can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/836624/2553526)

Comment: Thank you, but how to check for an unoccupied chess board square then?

Comment: if ([row objectAtIndex:i] == [NSNull null]) // Your statements

Comment: Actually [NSNull null] will return singleton of nil so that we can easily compare it without any pointer(Address) issues