# NSDictionary key/value Concepts

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a Question:
when we access an "**objectForKey**"and the key doesn't exist, this ll return **nil** but no error/exception, so the question is that after this statement/line is executed, does the runtime system creates a **key** with the name specified and set it **nil** OR although **nil** is the output but no such **key** is created????

Comment: and how can i list just the keys of a dictionary??

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary allkeys])` . it will give you all keys of that dictionary;

Comment: dear i syntax was not correct, so i did it like this NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary allKeys]); anyhow thanks :)

Comment: It was hand written. sorry for that. :)

Comment: its ok i myself still new to objective c:) thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it wont modify the dictionary. If the key does not exist then it simply returns nil value.

To confirm this you can set a breakpoint in Xcode for an invalid key and check if dictionary is modified or not. (And moreover NSDictionary is immutable i.e you cannot add/remove objects)

Comment: and in case of NSMutableDictionary ll u answer to YES???  If the key does not exist then will it still returns nil value + no creation of that key??

Comment: @iOS_Developer Why dont you check it out by debugging ;)

Comment: and this nil shows that no such key exists OR there is no value for this key, kindly tell me specifically

Comment: @iOS_Developer Nil returned means there is no such key. It cannot mean there is no value associated with this key because NSDictionary cannot hold `nil` value (`[NSNull null]` is allowed). Same holds good for NSArray and Mutable classes as well. If you do insert a nil value it will crash if not handled properly.

Comment: and [NSNull null] ll store nil as an object in a key, right??

Comment: They are both different, in a way yes `[NSNull null]` allows you to store NULL value objects. Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836601/whats-the-difference-between-nsnull-null-and-nil) for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

In a word: No.

`NSDictionary` is *immutable* and `objectForKey` is a method on the `NSDictionary` class.

Comment: @iOS_Developer No, same answer.

Comment: No.  And you can't put the value nil into an NSDictionary (or any collection class like NSArray or NSSet for that matter).  Try it.  If you do it explicitly Xcode won't compile your code.  If you try to insert a variable with a value of nil you'll get an exception.

Comment: @BrandonRoth yes i just got it from someone else, so to store nil [NSNull null] ll return an object with nil value, right???

Comment: @iOS_Developer No, it will return the (singleton) `NSNull` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Log` your dictionary after the line executed to see it.

You will see that `NSDictionary` is immutable, it won't modify your dictionary. ;)

Comment: @iOS_Developer Yes, same answer ! you can try to check it with breakpoint in XCode